# How to enable PowerShell script execution?

Tags: windows-10, security, powershell, security-policy

I would like to execute [a script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Set-CsCustomPresenceps1-in-8c78d094). Unfortunely my system refuses to do that (from an elevated prompt):

```
PS C:\Users\x\Desktop> .\Set-CustomPresence.ps1
.\Set-CustomPresence.ps1: File C:\Users\x\Desktop\Set-CustomPresence.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
```

I forced an `Undefined` state following the [advice above](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7):

```
PS C:\Users\x\Desktop> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

**The error is still the same and the script refuses to start**. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a less restrictive execution policy.

Run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

When prompted, choose the answer most appropriate to you.

> Execution Policy Change
>   The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
>   you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
>   https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
>   [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"):

Comment: @WoJ for the sake of your Systems security, set it to `RemoteSigned` instead of `Unrestricted`. `RemoteSigned` means that Scripts that you downloaded from the Internet need to be signed in order to run, which means malicious scripts can't run since they're most likely not signed. You can `Unblock-File -Path <pathtoscript>` to run unsigned scripts. I have it on `RemoteSigned` and haven't had the need to Unblock yet. Most official scripts from microsoft are signed anyhow. https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7

Comment: That's fair @SimonS, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Would be interesting to know what `Unblock-File` actually does, since it seem different from the execution policies. Any ideas?

Comment: @not2qubit that's a different question.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way to enable it manually

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then write `regedit`, then click yes.
- Open these paths in order: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\`
- Click 'Microsoft.PowerShell'
- Right click `ExecutionPolicy` then click '**Modify**'
- Set it to `RemoteSigned` then click save;
  Now enjoy your scripts

Comment: There are no items in this location in `W11 Home`. Has it moved?